# JSON.parse convert string to array error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

So I am trying to write this function that calculates the average based on values in a string by first converting it to an array with JSON.parse. I am getting an error on the JSON.parse and I am not sure why.

***"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N"***
line: var elmt = JSON.parse('[' + string + ']');

```
    function averageRisk() {
            var sum = 0;
            var string = +health_grab; 
            // this returns a string from my database like this: 8,5,3,5,2,6,8,9

            var elmt = JSON.parse('[' + string + ']');

            console.log("healthLevels: " + elmt);

            for (var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++) {
                        sum += parseInt(elmt[i].value, 10); 
            }

            if (isNaN(sum)) {
                        return false;
            }

            avg = Math.round(sum / elmt.length);

            console.log("Sum: " + sum);
            console.log("Average: " + avg);
    }
```

Comment: your string is `NaN`, what is the plus in `+health_grab` for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) `+` operator on `+health_grab`. This attempts to convert it into a number. This doesn't work and it produces [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

`JSON.parse()` tries and fails to parse `NaN` resulting in the error when it reaches the first character `N`.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N

Remove the `+` and it should fix the error.

Comment: this fixed it. I thought that I needed the "+" to bring it in from the database as numbers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo on your third line. You have an extra "+". When I test this in Node.JS I get the same error as you. Remove the "+" and it should work.

If this isn't a typo, what were you attempting to achieve with the prefixed "+"?